# Performing for loop in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV like the below:

```
i,ix,iz,iy,u'
0,1,1,1,-0.8696748576752853
1,1,1,2,2.3557976585107454
2,1,1,3,0.47209618683697663
3,1,1,4,-1.930481713597933
4,1,1,5,-1.7868247414530511
5,1,1,6,-0.5603642778861779
6,1,1,7,0.24540750240253573
7,1,1,8,0.5505270314521304
8,1,1,9,-0.1954277406567968
9,1,1,10,-1.3521265193776344
```

How to achieve values from u' when certain conditions are imposed in ix,iy,iz? For example, I would like to perform a `for` like the above:

```
for iy in list1:
    for iz in list2:
        for ix in list3:
           U = 2*df.iloc[a,4] ## `a` is just a row resulted from the the for's combination.
```

Furthermore, the whole CSV have 128^3 rows. This is the best way to perform loop in pandas? There's another faster way?

Comment: can you clarify where `a` comes from? is it related to `iy`, `iz` and `ix`?

Comment: Is just a position defined by the values of iy, iz and ix. For example, if iy=1, iz=1 and ix=1, `a` should be the first row.

Comment: do you want to get all the `u'` if their respective `iy`, `iz` and `ix` are contained in `list1`, `list2`, and `list3`?

Comment: are these lists of indices?

Comment: Is just a list containg the values of ix,iy,iz. In this case, a simple range(1,128).

Comment: `return` will exit the loops...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
df[(df["ix"] == ix) & (df["iy"] == iy) & (df["iz"] == iz)]["u'"]
```

to get a `Series` of `"u'"` where its row meets your `ix` / `iy` / `iz` conditions. You would put this in your for loop if you had multiple `ix` / `iy` / `iz` conditions.  Note that because there may be multiple rows that meet a particular condition, a `Series` is returned.

If you're only interested in a particular value (let's say the first if only one row is guaranteed to meet your particular condition), then you can index this `Series` with `[0]`.

Though if it's a possibility that a condition has no matching rows at all, you would want to make sure the `len` of this `Series` is `> 0` before indexing it.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, conditional statements can be written like this:

```
df[
  (df['ix'] == ix) &
  (df['iy'] == iy) &
  (df['iz'] == iz)
]["u'"]
```

In order to also iterate over the items in the mentioned lists, you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
for ix, iy, iz in itertools.product(list1, list2, list3):
    output = df[
      (df['ix'] == ix) &
      (df['iy'] == iy) &
      (df['iz'] == iz)
    ]["u'"]
```